# Not able to initialize getSupportFragementManager in PagerAdapter Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display the Google map in ViewPager in PagerAdapter Adapter class, When I am trying to initialise the Google Map Fragement, I am not able to. Here is my code :

```
public class GraphAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<GraphModel> graphModels;
    private Activity activity;


    public GraphAdapter(Context context, List<GraphModel> graphModels, Activity activity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.graphModels = graphModels;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return graphModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_component,container, false);
        FontsEngine.overrideTypeface_SemiBold(context,view);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); 
}
```

I am getting error:

> Cannot resolve the getSupportFragementManager

Any suggestions will be a great help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Activity in constructor parameter, you can try to use `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`.